# Kubernetes visual overview

Tags: software-testing

I am a begginer on Kubernetes and I wonder if there is a tool which I can connect to my cluster/node to get a visual feedback of what is inside it. Because sometimes I launch a deployment (or a anything else) and it's hard to know what I really do.

I use Mininkube and I already used the "dashboard" but it's not what I need.
What I want is something like this:

[image]

... with my live cluster/node architecture, the ports oppened, the mounted volumes and more.

Do you know if anything like this exists?